# How to create a bootstrap action for Impala on EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, impala

The latest version of Impala that I can find an EMR bootstrap action [This one](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/impala) this is from 2015 and installs Impala 2.2.0

Is there an easy way to update this to 2.7 or 2.8?  Spinning up an Ubuntu 14.04 box to do a build is one option, but I'm unclear how to ultimately install it on an EMR cluster.

Answer (score 0):

As this moment, there is no documented script to easily update impala to work on EMR. Its a sys admin thing and yes, you might look at the install script and tweak it to include your own build. Also, make sure you have all dependencies.

Once you install it, you will need to ensure you have  relevant configuration files placed somewhere in the CLASSPATH established by set-classpath.sh for Impala's use of EMR's HDFS, HBase , Hive metastore or S3 .